# Give an example of a set $A$, for which $A\cap [1,4] = A\cap N$ and $A\setminus Z \neq\emptyset $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Would an example be $A = \{1.5, 2.5\}$? I don't know for sure because my textbook has no solutions.

Comment: Well, with your example we have $A\cap [1,4]=A$ but $A\cap \mathbb N=\emptyset$.

Comment: Note:  to fix your example, all you need is for the elements of your set $A$ to lie outside the closed interval $[1,4]$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try  $A=\{\sqrt{17}\}$.